# Stitch edge of disk to edge of square in 3D space (with deformations)

Tags: graphics3d, topology

Topologically each point on the edge of a square can be mapped uniquelly (including the corners?) to a point on the edge of a circle.

It seems it might be possible to deform in 3D space the square and the disc so that they can be joined at the edge without any gaps. A colleague managed to do that in the real world with paper objects. Obviously this is not a precise result, so it may be wrong.

As a commenter said, the deformation should be isometric.

Can you make *Mathematica* solve this problem and generate a 3D surface showing a isometrically deformed square and disc joined at the edge?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Pictures taken from http://www.unitaryflow.com/2015/03/round-squares-exist.html

Comment: You need more constraints on your problem.  I can just generate you e.g. a cube with a face cut off, and assert that "this is a deformed circle."

Comment: @djp: Given the example of paper cutouts, I assume that the deformation is meant to be isometric. See also: [dForm](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/dform/)

Comment: @Rahul interesting.  I wish the OP had a little more of "this is what I've tried" etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
circ := {Cos[#], Sin[#]} &

quad = Interpolation[
  Table[{f, {Cos[f], Sin[f]}}, {f, 0, 2 π, π/2}], 
  InterpolationOrder -> 1]

ParametricPlot3D[{quad[t] z + circ[t] (1 - z), z} // Flatten, 
  {t, 0, 2 π}, {z, 0, 1}, 
  Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.8], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution has the original square, disc, and adds an interpolating wall between them. This is not what was requested. The solution must not add a extra surface (the wall)